# How to force the contents of a div to be on one line?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a Vite/Vue application styled with Tailwind CSS. I cannot understand why the content of several automatically generated `<div>` is wrapped instead of being on one line.

I tried to reproduce this from scratch but whatever I tried behaved as expected.

I finally copied the generated HTML and the problem is reproduced. The code is below, also available at [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/QTzXQFwxnD).

```html
<div class="flex flex-row items-start gap-5">
  <!--v-if-->
  <div data-v-c5bff582="" class="">
    <!-- important events within 8 days -->
    <div data-v-c5bff582="" class="flex flex-auto flex-row gap-3">
      <div data-v-c5bff582="" class="w-32 rounded-3xl bg-green-200 px-5 py-1 text-center text-2xl text-gray-400">test later 1</div>
      <div data-v-c5bff582="" class="w-32 rounded-3xl bg-green-200 px-5 py-1 text-center text-2xl text-gray-400">test 2 later</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="self-end rounded-md bg-slate-500 px-5 py-2 text-4xl text-white">dump store</button>
</div>
```

My problem is with "test later 1" and "test 2 later". Why aren't they on one line but wrapped in the `<div>`?

[image]

I tried all kinds of combinations of classes (and to be frank, a bit whatever-I-could-think-of as I was reading the Tailwind CSS docs) but without success (I learned quite a bit of Tailwind CSS though)

Comment: The Tailwind Play shows them on a single line. Could you add an image explaining your problem?

Comment: I see them wrapped.   Your `w-32` class sets a specific width of 8 rem on those elements, and you have more than 8 rems worth of text in them.  If you want them on one line, choose a width that suits your content (or don't specify a fixed width in the first place.)

Comment: @0stone0: you see the *content* of the divs on one line? I added a picture for clarity

Comment: Ahhh, misunderstood, thought it was about the buttons themself. Daniel is right, enlarge the button, or add the `whitespace-nowrap` Tailwind class to prevent wrapping.

Comment: @0stone0 I tried `whitespace-nowrap` but it broke the visuals (the text was getting outside the button) - but with all my tests i may have had the wrong combination (but the visual was broken for sure)

Comment: Yes, `white-space: nowrap` is not a solution because it doesn't address the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin: I tried that but I think (wildly guessing) that my `w-32` was forcing the width (removing it fixed the issue)

Comment: @DanielBeck: it worked, and I do not remember why `w-32` was there in the first place. Would you mind turning the comment into an answer?

Comment: Sure thing, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `w-32` class sets a fixed width on the element (in this case 8 rems);  the content needs more space than that so wraps to the next line.

If you want the buttons to be of uniform fixed size, choose a larger fixed width; otherwise you can just remove the `w-*` class and let the elements find their natural size.